# Optimization method

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem:
[\begin{array}{l}
\mathop {\max }\limits_{x,y} f(x,y)\\
0 \le x \le g(y)\\
0 \le y \le 1
\end{array}]

f is non linear in x and y.

f is increasing in x and decreasing in y.
g(y) is increasing in y.
Can we take x=g(y) to maximize f over x than after replacing x by g(y) in the expression of f we maximize f over y.
the problem is now:
[\begin{array}{l}
\mathop {\max }\limits_{y} f(g(y),y)\\
0 \le y \le 1
\end{array}]

Is that possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. For any given $y$, the best choice of $x$ is $g(y)$. So $x$ can be eliminated from the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that makes me feel better, I already build a hole work based on this solution